# Delete directory recursive fails for filtered-out directory?

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

I wrote this command for remove specific directories:

```
Get-ChildItem M:\ -recurse -Directory -Exclude images,record |
  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) } |
  Select-String "\d{8}" |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf -ErrorAction Stop
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\delete_old_pics\InputStream' because it does
not exist.
At line:1 char:151
+ ... ring "\d{8}" | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf -ErrorAction Stop
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\delete_old_pics\InputStream:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Someone to help me with this?

Edit #1 (add directory output - search working properly):

```
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151016
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151017
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151018
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151019
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151020
M:\S6-Warehouse\20151021
```

Edit #2
Work with one more parameter:
`| Select -ExpandProperty Line` before
`| Remove-Item -Force`

and with Ansgar suggestion

Comment: What is the point of this `Select-String "\d{8}"`? It will be returning match objects. Are you looking for folders with _only_ 8 digits in them?

Comment: See above, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-String` operates on the entire input object, not just the path, and it returns a `MatchInfo` object, not the matched path (or input object). I'd suggest extending the `Where-Object` filter instead of using `Select-String`:

```
Get-ChildItem M:\ -Recurse -Directory -Exclude images,record | Where-Object {
  $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) -and
  $_.BaseName -match '^\d{8}$'
} | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf -ErrorAction Stop
```

As @Matt pointed out in his comment you may want to anchor the expression (`^`/`$`) to avoid matching names like `foo12345678` or `1234567890`.

Comment: Might suggest a anchored match since that will match folders with more than eight characters

Answer (score -3):

You should try this for your query:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path your_absolute_path -Exclude '*.png' |
  Where-Object { $_. LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) } |
  Select-String "\d{8}" |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Enforcing or suppressing confirmation has nothing to do with the issue at hand here.